# Explanation of the Kalman Filter

Tags: kalman-filter

I am a beginner in robotics, and I am learning about the Kalman filter. I do not seem to get it, though. I am a mathematician, and so it would be helpful if the Kalman filter could be explained in a mathematical method.

Comment: Hi Sanath. As it is your question is too general. It would help considerably if you could elaborate.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to understand it from practical perspective. From mathematical point of view, it is matrix multiplications and it is simple. I understood the concept by simulating simple systems in Matlab in the presence of noise. The goal is to estimate the state vector in the presence of noise which makes sense to build such a system that has noise. Check out the [INTERACTIVE COURSE ON EKF AND SLAM](http://www.joansola.eu/JoanSola/eng/course.html).